# Deploy a multi-module project with Maven Cargo

Tags: maven, maven-cargo

In this project I'm working on, I have a big master pom file defining several modules (domain, dao, service, war).

I want to deploy my war to my remote tomcat server using Cargo.

running mvn cargo:deploy -Ptest however gives me an error that the dependency for the module domain in the module dao could not be resolved.

I've tried putting the cargo config in the war pom but still the same.

Can someone help me?

This is the parent POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>product</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Internal dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-domain</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product.dao</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-dao-api</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product.dao</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-dao-jpa2</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product.service</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-service-api</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product.service</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-service-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.domain.product</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-war</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <type>war</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- profiles -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment.type</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <modules>
        <module>product-domain</module>
        <module>product-dao-api</module>
        <module>product-dao-jpa2</module>
        <module>product-service-api</module>
        <module>product-service-impl</module>
        <module>product-war</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

This is the WAR POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>product</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.domain.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-war</artifactId>
    <name>product</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain.product.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>product-service-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain.product.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>product-service-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment.type</name>
                    <value>test</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Deployment settings -->
                <cargo.containerId>tomcat7x</cargo.containerId>
                <cargo.baseurl>http://test.domain.net:8080</cargo.baseurl>
                <container.url>${cargo.baseurl}/manager/text</container.url>
                <container.user>tomcat-txt</container.user>
                <container.password>password</container.password>
                <container.pingurl>${cargo.baseurl}/${project.name}/index.html</container.pingurl>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <wait>true</wait>
                            <container>
                                <containerId>${cargo.containerId}</containerId>
                                <type>remote</type>
                            </container>
                            <configuration>
                                <type>runtime</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.remote.uri>${container.url}</cargo.remote.uri>
                                    <cargo.remote.username>${container.user}</cargo.remote.username>
                                    <cargo.remote.password>${container.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                            <deployer>
                                <deployables>
                                    <deployable>
                                        <groupId>com.domain.product</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>product-war</artifactId>
                                        <type>war</type>
                                        <properties>
                                            <context>${project.name}</context>
                                        </properties>
                                        <pingURL>${container.pingurl}</pingURL>
                                    </deployable>
                                </deployables>
                            </deployer>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

As you can see, the war is dependent from the service, which by itself is dependent from the dao and that one from the domain.

Comment: Not enough information. Please attach pom.xml for the module that you're trying to deploy.

Comment: Would this answer help on how to do multi-module deployments with cargo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21190644/219304 ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you have to use first a mvn install and than

```
mvn -pl product-war cargo:deploy -Ptest
```